# How to monitor Memory utilization of the single process?

Tags: memory, monitoring

How to monitor Memory and CPU usage of the single process by program/executable name(not PID);

Comment: try `top -p PID`

Answer (score 2):

Try this. if you want with program name

```
   mypid=`pidof programname` ; top -p $mypid
```

OR

```
     top -p `pidof programname`
```

Answer (score 0):

To monitor **one** or **more** instances matching the name:

`top -p$(pgrep <program> | tr '\n' ',' | head -c -1)`

Use `pgrep -f` to search the whole command lines for matches.

(Works with `htop` too.)